# How to Disable the search button once it is clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, button

I am in need of Disabling the search button once it is clicked. This needs to be appended in the following code.

```
<form class="search-head" id="frmSearch" action="<%= resultString %>" method="get">
    <input name="q" class="<%=cssName%> search-tags" id="tags" value="q" maxlength=50 />

    <input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="utf-8" />
    <input type="hidden" id="searchLabel" name="searchLabel" value='<%=currentStyle.get("searchLabel", "")%>' />
        <c:if test="${enableSpringerSearch eq true}">
            <button type="button" class="change-search-engine">${springerButtonLabel}</button>
        </c:if>
    <button type="submit"><fmt:message key="label_button"/></button>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What did you examine yourself? Look at the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate function to handle it:

```
document.getElementById("idOfButton").onclick = function() {
    //disable
    this.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I embed this into the above code. Can I add after <button type="submit"  ><fmt:message key="label_button"/></button>

Comment: Assign an id to your button like `<button id = myButton type=submit>` and instead of `"idOfButton"` in JS code put `"myButton"`. Whenever the button is clicked, it will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function disableBtn() {
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="utf-8" />
<input type="hidden" id="searchLabel" name="searchLabel" value='<%=currentStyle.get("searchLabel", "")%>' />
    <c:if test="${enableSpringerSearch eq true}">
        <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="disableBtn()"  class="change-search-engine">search</button>
    </c:if>
<button type="submit"  ><fmt:message key="label_button"/></button>
```

Comment: it is not working, the code is displayed near the search icon.<input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="utf-8" />
 <input type="hidden" id="searchLabel" name="searchLabel" value='<%=currentStyle.get("searchLabel", "")%>' />
        <c:if test="${enableSpringerSearch eq true}">
            <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="disableBtn()" class="change-search-engine">${springerButtonLabel}</button>
        </c:if>
    <button type="submit"><fmt:message key="label_button"/></button>
        function disableBtn() {
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
        }